# what causes my headlamps to stop turning off automatically?

Tags: headlight

i have a 2004 Toyota Tundra. just recently the headlights would not turn off automatically when i turned off the key and opened the door.

Comment: Did you accidentally turn the headlight selector? On Toyota's it would be the turn signal lever (left of the steering wheel), it also spins on its axis to change the headlight settings

Comment: no, for many years i would leave the headlight setting on and when i exited the truck the lights would turn off automatically. now they wont turn off unless i do it manually

Comment: I think this may have happened by turning lights from Auto to on when the key was in the ignition, but in the off position.  I think I fixed it by switching the ignition on, lights to auto, then to on, then removing the key.  Not sure exactly.  Highlander 2005.